# Ping inconsistent but works just to different address

Tags: networking, ping

When I ping a static external IP address on my internal network it works half the time directly to the IP address but then half the time it is going to the router address first. Is there some things I can test here to see why it isn't just consistent? I have another external IP address not on that server that pings consistently without going to the router.

Here is the inconsistent ping:

PING 70.88.182.194 (70.88.182.194): 56 data bytes 
64 bytes from 70.88.182.194: icmp_seq=0 ttl=63 time=1.834 ms
64 bytes from 70.88.182.194: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=1.846 ms
64 bytes from 70.88.182.194: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.128 ms
92 bytes from 10.1.10.1: Redirect Host(New addr: 70.88.182.194)
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 0054 4ba0   0 0000  3f  01 1e34 10.1.10.186  70.88.182.194 

64 bytes from 70.88.182.194: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.183 ms
92 bytes from 10.1.10.1: Redirect Host(New addr: 70.88.182.194)
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 0054 ebb3   0 0000  3f  01 7e20 10.1.10.186  70.88.182.194 

64 bytes from 70.88.182.194: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1.117 ms
92 bytes from 10.1.10.1: Redirect Host(New addr: 70.88.182.194)
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 0054 b051   0 0000  3f  01 b982 10.1.10.186  70.88.182.194 

64 bytes from 70.88.182.194: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=1.154 ms
64 bytes from 70.88.182.194: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=1.133 ms
92 bytes from 10.1.10.1: Redirect Host(New addr: 70.88.182.194)
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 0054 8411   0 0000  3f  01 e5c2 10.1.10.186  70.88.182.194 

64 bytes from 70.88.182.194: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=1.072 ms
64 bytes from 70.88.182.194: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=1.508 ms
64 bytes from 70.88.182.194: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.943 ms
92 bytes from 10.1.10.1: Redirect Host(New addr: 70.88.182.194)
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 0054 ca19   0 0000  3f  01 9fba 10.1.10.186  70.88.182.194 

64 bytes from 70.88.182.194: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=2.307 ms
64 bytes from 70.88.182.194: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=0.927 ms
64 bytes from 70.88.182.194: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=0.945 ms
64 bytes from 70.88.182.194: icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=3.285 ms

Routing tables 

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire

default            10.1.10.1          UGSc          456       11     en6

10.1.10/24         link#10            UCS            86        0     en6

10.1.10.1/32       link#10            UCS             3        0     en6

10.1.10.1          78:cd:8e:c7:92:b7  UHLWIir       457        0     en6   1029

10.1.10.2          20:c9:d0:32:9e:19  UHLWIi          1      689     en6    114

10.1.10.5          link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.6          link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.7          link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.8          link#10            UHLWIi          1      419     en6

10.1.10.10         0:c:29:e4:b4:54    UHLWIi          1        0     en6    743

10.1.10.11         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.13         b8:9:8a:d5:19:1b   UHLWIi          1     1483     en6   1068

10.1.10.14         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.15         d0:df:9a:7e:b2:1e  UHLWIi          1        0     en6   1196

10.1.10.16         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.17         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.18         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.20         link#10            UHLWIi          1        9     en6

10.1.10.21         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.22         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.23         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.24         link#10            UHLWIi          1      835     en6

10.1.10.27         link#10            UHLWIi          1     1375     en6

10.1.10.29         link#10            UHLWIi          1       15     en6

10.1.10.30         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.31         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.32         ec:b1:d7:f9:eb:d9  UHLWIi          1        0     en6   1194

10.1.10.35         f0:d1:a9:f:28:9c   UHLWIi          1        0     en6    742

10.1.10.36         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.37         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.40         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.41         b8:9:8a:da:69:4b   UHLWIi          1     1133     en6     38

10.1.10.42         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.43         link#10            UHLWIi          1      173     en6

10.1.10.44         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.45         link#10            UHLWIi          1       70     en6

10.1.10.46         link#10            UHLWIi          1        4     en6

10.1.10.47         c8:2a:14:22:cc:47  UHLWIi          1        0     en6    596

10.1.10.48         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.49         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.50         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.52         link#10            UHLWIi          1        1     en6

10.1.10.53         link#10            UHLWIi          1     1241     en6

10.1.10.57         f8:4:2e:2f:e2:1f   UHLWIi          1     2282     en6   1198

10.1.10.58         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.59         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.62         b8:9:8a:da:a2:dd   UHLWIi          1        0     en6    991

10.1.10.63         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.64         link#10            UHLWIi          1        3     en6

10.1.10.65         link#10            UHLWIi          1      377     en6

10.1.10.66         link#10            UHLWIi          1        2     en6

10.1.10.67         link#10            UHLWIi          1     1865     en6

10.1.10.69         f8:4:2e:2f:e2:48   UHLWIi          1     2290     en6   1199

10.1.10.70         link#10            UHLWIi          1      278     en6

10.1.10.71         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.74         link#10            UHLWIi          1       30     en6

10.1.10.75         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.76         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.77         link#10            UHLWIi          1       44     en6

10.1.10.78         link#10            UHLWIi          1       93     en6

10.1.10.79         f8:4:2e:30:1:9e    UHLWIi          1     2217     en6   1200

10.1.10.80         f0:d1:a9:f:28:9c   UHLWIi          1    19044     en6   1199

10.1.10.82         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.83         link#10            UHLWIi          1     2379     en6

10.1.10.85         0:19:f:f:1a:f3     UHLWIi          1      228     en6   1092

10.1.10.87         90:2b:34:a4:f4:76  UHLWIi          1        0     en6   1196

10.1.10.88         2c:27:d7:46:b3:91  UHLWIi          1        0     en6   1199

10.1.10.89         ac:87:a3:27:eb:b7  UHLWIi          1      253     en6   1132

10.1.10.90         link#10            UHLWIi          1     1516     en6

10.1.10.92         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.93         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.94         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.95         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.96         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.97         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.99         link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.100        link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.102        68:94:23:9c:6:59   UHLWIi          1        0     en6   1054

10.1.10.112        90:2:a9:b:a0:89    UHLWIi          1        0     en6   1053

10.1.10.113        90:2:a9:b:a0:7d    UHLWIi          1        0     en6   1053

10.1.10.114        90:2:a9:b:a0:76    UHLWIi          1        0     en6   1068

10.1.10.115        90:2:a9:b:a0:6f    UHLWIi          1        0     en6   1053

10.1.10.151        40:6c:8f:b8:44:f9  UHLWIi          3    64070     en6   1193

10.1.10.152        link#10            UHLWIi          1    75508     en6

10.1.10.154        a8:20:66:34:9c:57  UHLWIi          5   829447     en6   1200

10.1.10.155        0:c:29:ad:cc:69    UHLWIi          1  1286634     en6    996

10.1.10.186/32     link#10            UCS             2        0     en6

10.1.10.186        98:5a:eb:ca:a4:59  UHLWIi          1        1     lo0

10.1.10.240        0:e0:81:79:d5:70   UHLWIi          1      110     en6    120

10.1.10.248        link#10            UHLWIi          1        0     en6

10.1.10.255        link#10            UHLWbI          1    13902     en6

127                127.0.0.1          UCS             1        0     lo0

127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              8   553203     lo0

169.254            link#10            UCS            13        0     en6

169.254.56.167     link#10            UHLSW           1        0     en6

169.254.91.253     link#10            UHLSW           1        0     en6

169.254.113.79     link#10            UHLSW           1        0     en6

169.254.132.235    link#10            UHLSW           1        0     en6

169.254.144.221    link#10            UHLSW           1        0     en6

169.254.168.44     link#10            UHLSW           1        0     en6

169.254.178.55     link#10            UHLSW           1        0     en6

169.254.197.234    link#10            UHLSW           1        0     en6

169.254.233.20     link#10            UHLSW           1        0     en6

169.254.237.115    link#10            UHLSW           1        0     en6

169.254.243.228    link#10            UHLSW           1        0     en6

169.254.247.120    link#10            UHLSW           1        0     en6

172.16.58/24       link#13            UC              3        0  vmnet8

172.16.58.255      link#13            UHLWbI          1    13902  vmnet8

172.16.222/24      link#12            UC              3        0  vmnet1

172.16.222.255     link#12            UHLWbI          1    13902  vmnet1

224.0.0            link#10            UmCS            2        0     en6

224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI          1     1364     en6

255.255.255.255/32 link#10            UCS             2        0     en6

255.255.255.255    link#10            UHLWbI          1    10106     en6

chadps:~ chadsims$ networksetup -listallhardwareports

Hardware Port: Display Ethernet

Device: en6

Ethernet Address: 98:5a:eb:ca:a4:59


Hardware Port: Display FireWire

Device: fw0

Ethernet Address: 00:0a:27:02:00:65:ab:29


Hardware Port: Wi-Fi

Device: en0

Ethernet Address: a4:5e:60:e4:66:f1


Hardware Port: Bluetooth PAN

Device: en4

Ethernet Address: a4:5e:60:e4:53:6c


Hardware Port: Thunderbolt 1

Device: en1

Ethernet Address: 6a:00:00:3b:6a:f0


Hardware Port: Thunderbolt 2

Device: en2

Ethernet Address: 6a:00:00:3b:6a:f1


Hardware Port: Thunderbolt Bridge

Device: bridge0

Ethernet Address: a6:5e:60:4e:97:00


VLAN Configurations

Comment: What you are seeing are ICMP redirects however something is odd. ICMP redirects are used to let hosts know if there is a better next hop gateway to a particular destination other than the one they are currently using. In your case, when you ping 70.88.182.194, your (default?) gateway at 10.1.10.1 is saying "to get to 70.88.182.194, you should send packets to 70.88.182.194 as the next hop, rather than me."


Can you post the output of your routing table and interface config.

Comment: What makes this odd, is that the RFC standard says that routers should only send an ICMP redirect when the "better" next-hop gateway (e.g. 70.88.182.194) is in the same subnet as the source IP of the original packet (e.g. 10.1.10.186).

Comment: We have a strange setup I think because our gw is our router rather than using a separate router. So there may be some routing tables in the gw/router that I can't see but public WAN for the gw is 70.88.182.198 and router is 10.1.10.1 but like I can ping 70.88.182.196 which is not on 70.88.182.197 server and it pings fine.  It is only when I try to ping ip addresses within the server that is 70.88.182.197 (local 10.1.10.151) when I have the ICMP issue you are seeing.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused about where these servers sit on your network - a quick network diagram may help.  Correct me if I'm wrong: the device that you are testing from is 10.1.10.186 and the internal IP of your default gateway is 10.1.10.1. The public IP of your default gateway is 70.88.182.198. Where do the servers sit? It sounds like they sit on the same subnet as your PC however I'm unclear how they each get a public IP - do they don't use 10.1.10.1 as their default gateway?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8kasejdkkvu9bs/Screenshot%202016-06-11%2013.33.36.png?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm still not 100% sure of your setup however the issue is, the router 10.1.10.1 thinks that you should be able to send a ping to 70.88.182.194 directly rather than it having to be routed through itself. If I was to guess why this only happened on the .197 server, it would be because the .197 server also has an address in your PC's own subnet (10.1.10.0/24?).

As I mentioned before, ICMP redirects should only be sent when the recommended next hop is in the same subnet as the originating host (definitely not in your case) so this could be a bug with the Router itself.

Comment: You should check the routing table on the router and investigate the make/model to see if there are any known issues.

Comment: both are on the same subnet 255.255.255.0 which ISP says that 70.88.182.198 gw and I'm guessing the static IP block is 255.255.255.248? Should I change my static IP addresses to this?